# compile babylon.d.ts using tsconfig

Tags: typescript, babylonjs

I am trying to compile my `.ts` files using below configuration in `tsconfig.json`.

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "./",
      "outDir": "./src/js",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "declaration": false,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "target": "es5",
      "types": []
    }
  }
```

But it compile all `.ts` files except `babylon.d.ts` file.

Here is my dir structure.

[image]

As you can see I have another `.ts` file i.e game.ts file inside ts folder. it got compile and generate js file, but babylon.js file not getting generated.

Answer (score 0):

When a file has the `.d.ts` file extension, it means it is an [*ambient declaration*, or *ambient module*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#working-with-other-javascript-libraries) that provides type information during compilation - but has no implementation.

If you look inside `babylon.d.ts` you'll see that it is quite abstract - and doesn't actually have the code needed to run.

This is why there is no output, because everything in the file is subject to type-erasure.

You need to provide the implementation file at runtime.

Comment: Correct. It is abstract. so `You need to provide the implementation file at runtime.` means I need to add reference of js file?

Comment: @Programmer you need to bring your own `babel.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

Just add it in the types array in you ts.config file